# Recursively call function to get last record in a chain

Tags: php

In our database, we have records in a single table where the ID of one record is the parentID of another. For example:

| ID | ParentID |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | null |
| 456 | 123 |
| 789 | 456 |
| 011 | 789 |

There is an existing function named `getchild` that can be passed an ID to get a child. For example calling `getChild(456)` would return record with ID 789. If no child exists, `NULL` is returned. So for another example, calling `getChild(011)` would return null, since no record has this as a parentID. getChild returns the data as a PHP object.

I'd like to create a separate function (named getLastChild) that takes the first ID in the chain and recursively calls getChild() until the last record is reached and return it. For example `getLastchild(123)` should return record with ID 011.

This is what I've tried so far that is not working

```
public function getLastChild($id){
    $child = getChild($id);
    while(!is_null($child)){
        $lastChild = getChild($child->id);
    }
    return $lastChild;
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: This may be faster to implement in the database with recursive functionality. Postgres, SQL Server, Oracle, etc all have a concept of "recursive CTE" that is built to do this very quickly and natively. Mysql can do this as well, but with variables and other black magic.

Comment: @JNevill MySQL 8.x now has recursive CTE.

Comment: @Barmar It's really coming into its own! Soon you'll be telling me that SQL Server can natively handle regular expressions.

Comment: @JNevill, thanks for that insight, however the platform we are developing on only allows us to use ROQL which we can only use to write simple select queries leaving most of our work to be done programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your loop condition never changes because you're assigning `$lastChild` but testing `$child`. You don't need the `$lastChild` variable, just keep using `$child`.

```
public function getLastChild($id){
    $child = getChild($id);
    while(!is_null($child)){
        $child = getChild($child->id);
    }
    return $child;
}
```